# Translating python code to ruby

Tags: python, ruby

Alright, I'm new to ruby and I have this ID generator that Generates an ID based off of the Time.now.to_f/time.time() and then a 8 length id, for example this is the working python version

```
def anonId(a,b):
        a = a.split('.')[0]
        if len(a) > 4: i = a[6:]
        else: i = a
        return "".join(str(int(x) + int(y))[-1] for x, y in zip(i, b[4:]))
```

Doing

```
anonId("1379697991.99",'26002859')
```

Would generate the ID of '9740'
In ruby I have tried something like this, but I don't quite understand ruby enough yet to know how to do it but here is what I have so far

```
def anonId(number,id)
    if String(number).length > 4 then number = String(number).split(".")[0][-4..-1] else number end 
    [number,id[4..-1]].zip.each do |x,y|
       #this is where I get stuck at, I'm not sure if the above is correct

    end
end
```

So basically, I need to know how to convert that python code into ruby

Comment: I'm afraid in order to do that you need to learn both Python and Ruby.

Comment: What are you actually having trouble with? What's not coming out correctly? Have you looked at the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/)?

Comment: I know how the python works, but I started learning ruby yesterday and I'm just not positive on how to convert it. But I'll keep googling zip and ruby methods hopefuly I figure it out

Comment: You're not likely to find someone who will just convert the code for you, but if you have questions about what specific things are not working, we can hep you.

Comment: As a comment for the python, that's slightly bizarre logic that may or may not make sense in your environment.  First off, is there a reason you're not the time to a string before you remove the decimal (it seems like it'd be much cleaner to do t = int(time.time()) % 10000 and then cast that to a string).  Secondly, what if (you, um, went back in time and) a was 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 letters long (or in other-words you end up with your two lists being passed to zip not being the same length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In Ruby you can not just iterate over a string - you must specify how
  (lines, bytes, codepoints or chars).
- `zip` is a method on Array, use like `an_array.zip(other_array)`.
- If you want to iterate over an array (or any enumerable), do something with each element and store the result in an array, use `map`

This leads to `number.chars.zip(id[4..-1].chars).map do |x,y|`

Note x and y are strings. Convert them to integers with `x.to_i` etc.

Comment: Thank you that worked I really needed to know how to do that, you have no idea how much that helps.